# How can I make a colorramp over multiple objects?

Tags: shaders, color

I am trying to make a color transition over multiple objects.

[image]

it should be, that the leftmost tile is red and from then transition to blue on the right.
How do I manage to implement it?

Thank you guys in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would of course be to join them all in one object and use the *Generated* output of the *Texture Coordinate* node.

If you need to keep the elements separate, one way to achieve this would be to use the *Object* output of the *Texture Coordinate* node. With nothing in the *Object* field at the bottom this uses the coordinates of each object on itself, but if you specify an object like one of those elements or perhaps an empty, you can manipulate the coordinates through this object.

On objects where the scale is correctly applied, the coordinate output will be in Blender units. For example, if you take the default cube located at 0/0/0 with an edge length of 2 m, the coordinates will be 0 on all axes in the center and each axis -1 from the front bottom left to 1 at the back top right. Which means, all values are absolute measures in meters, not normalized 0 to 1 like the *Generated* output.

In my example I've just used the element on the left and a *Separate XYZ* node to spread the color gradient in X direction. Since all objects together are wider than 1 m but the *Color Ramp* only assigns values to the 0 to 1 range, I'm using a *Mapping* node to scale the coordinates down (you could also use a *Map Range* after the separate X output instead) on X and I also moved them on X to place the starting point of the gradient and rotated a little on Y to have a slightly slanted gradient.

Of course there are ways to calculate exact values if you need to place the gradient in a certain way, it all depends on your objects and their size and placement. For a quick solution you can of course adjust everything Pi mal Daumen.

[image: object coordinates]

For the sake of completeness, here is an example with a *Map Range* node and calculated values (don't need a *Mapping* node here because I'm not rotating the gradient):

Using the X coordinates of the reference object from my example, you get the following values: The origin of the reference object is at X = 2.4, this is X = 0 of the coordinate system.

The object has an X dimension of 1.49 m, which means the left side is at -(1.49/2) = -0.745 and this is the *From Min* value for the *Map Range* node.

The objects that are farthest away on X have their origin at X = 4.8, so first of all they are 2.4 + 4.8 = 7.2 meters away from the coordinate system's center. Since they have the same width, the farthest right vertex is at 7.2 + 0.745 = 7.945 m, this is the *From Max* value.

With the *Map Range* node this will be mapped to *To Min* = 0 and *To Max* = 1 so that the *Color Ramp* can distribute the gradient from left to right.

[image: mapped coordinates]